# react link vs a tag and arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I just started on react router.

I have two questions. What is the difference between using `<Link to="/page">` and `<a href="page">`? Both make the exact same get request to `/page` but I get an error when I use `<a href="page">` but it works when I use `<Link to="/page">` when I am nesting routes. I don't understand, how there could be any difference, when I know for fact that both render to exact same url?

Second is the weird arrow function in react router v4 documentation

```
const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)
```

I know `() => {}` these are new in ES6 but I cannot find anything on normal brackets instead of parentheses. What are they?

Edit

My index.js class (I have all the imports)

```
render((
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route component={App}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My App.js class

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <header>
                <span className="icn-logo"><i className="material-icons">code</i></span>
                <ul className="main-nav">
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/teachers">Teachers</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/courses">Courses</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </header>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/teachers" component={Teachers}/>
            <Route path="/courses" component={Course}/>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

The error I'm getting.
`Cannot GET /about` on the browser when I try to move to `localhost:8080/about`. However, when I click the `about` button, it goes to exactly the same url `/about` and renders perfectly

Comment: I'm confused, because `()` are parentheses ... so you know about braces `{}`, do you know when a `return` is implied in an arrow function and when it would be required if you need to return a value? do you also know when you would use `() => ({});` in an arrow function? oh, and basically, that function simply returns `<div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>`

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry I got the vocabs mixed up. But yes that was what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This may be a bit late to address your issue and you may well have figured it out. But here's my take:

**First:**

> What is the difference between using `<Link to="/page">` and `<a
>   href="page">`

- On the surface, you seem to be comparing apples and oranges here. The path in your anchor tag is a relative path while that one in the `Link` is absolute (rightly so, I don't think `react-router` supports relative paths yet). The problem this creates is say you are on `/blah`, while clicking on your `Link` will go to `/page`, clicking on the `<a href='page' />` will take you to `/blah/page`. This may not be an issue though since you confirmed the correctness of the url, but thought to note.
- A bit deeper difference, which is just an addon to @Dennis answer (and the docs he pointed to), is when you are already in a route that matches what the `Link` points to. Say we are currently on `/page` and the `Link` points to `/page` or even `/page/:id`, this won't trigger a full page refresh while an `<a />` tag naturally will. See issue [on Github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982).

A fix I used to solve my little need around this was to pass in a `state` property into link like so `<Link to={{pathname: "/page", state: "desiredState"}}>Page</Link>`. Then I can check for this in the target component's (say `<Page />`) `componentWillReceiveProps` like so:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if (nextProps.location.state === 'desiredState') {
    // do stuffs
  }
}
```

**Second question:**

> the weird arrow function in react router v4 documentation... I cannot find anything on normal brackets instead of parentheses. What are they?

Arrow functions; again @Dennis and @Jaromanda X have kind of addressed it. However, I've got three bits to add:

- When you have `() => blah` without the curly braces `{}`, you are implicitly returning whatever follows the `=>` in this case `blah`. But when you have curly braces immediately after the arrow, then it's now your responsibility to `return` something if you so desire. So `() => blah` (which by the way is synonymous to `() => (blah)`) will be more similar to `() => { return blah }` and not `() => { blah }`.
- So what happens if you want to return an object: `{ blah: blah }`; this is what @Jaromanda X was pointing at. You will then need to do `() => ({ blah: blah })` or simply `() => ({ blah })` for implicit return or you could return explicitly like so `() => { return { blah: blah } }`.
- My third bit is to point you to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Hope it helps.

Comment: In my case, I face the same problem that the react-router does change the URL but not the page contents. After I've tried your solution too it's not working. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @amrs-tech it's tedious to suggest without seeing what you're doing with your routes. A stab in the dark for you to try, however, will be to switch from using react-router `render` to using `component` props. That is if you're doing `<Route render={() => <YourComponent />} />`, try `<Route component={YourComponent} />` instead. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Good luck!

Comment: In react hooks, I had an issue with `<Link href="">`. The page would not load completly, but with `<a href="">` it did.

Answer (score 22):

The href attribute would trigger a page refresh which would reset the application states. However the link and navlink of react-router doesn't trigger a page refresh. Since React is used to create single page applications most of the time make sure you choose Link or Navlink when working with routing

Answer (score 3):

The  component allows you to do more than the normal  link element. For instance, because it's a React component you have the benefits of having a state and what not (if you want that). You can see more documentation on  [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link). Without the error I'm not sure what happens, but I suspect the routing library wants you to use the  component, over a normal html element.

With regards to `() => {}` this is a construct which is called an anonymous function, or a lambda expression. It's basically the same as saving a function in a variable: `var x = function(){ return (<div>...) };` if you have anything in the first parenthesis, it's a parameter which you have access to: `const x = (y) => return y*2;` The reason it's done in React is to expose the function scope to the component it lies in.

Comment: Hi I have edited to show the error and my classes. Do you think you know what the problem is?

Comment: @serendipity As long as you don't use any other funky business I am not entirely sure. <Link to="/something">Link</Link> changes the URI to /something, then your <Route path="/something" component={Something} /> should pick up on that and render whatever <Something /> is. You say it works with <a>, does that mean the correct component is rendered? You can try and compare your code to this one, which works. https://fiddle.jshell.net/terda12/mana88Lm/

Comment: as far as I know, routehandler is deprecated in React Route v4 and in v4, it seems like we have to put the route directly in the child class themselves. I am referring to this page https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Answer (score 3):

There is no better then looking at the code source.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js

You can see that `Link` is a component, that internally use **history**. Which is the module|library behind the history and navigation for react-router. And come with different modes (in memory history, browserHistory, hashHistory. And even custom).

Yea as a similarity it render an anchor tag  but  the default behavior is overridden (preventDefault()). They could have used just a div. But not completely right. As for the reason bellow.

So basically it work like that:

Observe the condition bellow

```
  if (
          !event.defaultPrevented && // onClick prevented default
          event.button === 0 && // ignore everything but left clicks
          (!this.props.target || this.props.target === "_self") && // let browser handle "target=_blank" etc.
          !isModifiedEvent(event) // ignore clicks with modifier keys
    ) {

}
```

if the condition above is met. It will use **history** (push or replace). Otherwise it will leave the browser normal behavior. And so in that case it will be just a normal anchor tag `<a />`. Example letting the browser handle target='blank'. The condition are well explained.
Then depending on the type of history object. The behavior change. Not the behavior of ` itself. But just the result of the history object type.

## In resume:

`<Link />` is a component, that render a `<a />` anchor tag. However in the main conditions the default behavior is prevented (`preventDefault()`). That allow it to apply the change to the history object (`onClick` event). Which react-router navigation is based on. And on the some conditions as mentioned above. It just fall back to the browser behavior. And just be exactly a `<a />` anchor tag (no `preventDefault()`).

For the use. If you are using React-router. Then you just need to use `Link`.