# Why use Link component in React-Router instead of just anchor tag?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-form

I am new to react-router and I understand that the `Link` component will be translated to Anchor tag. So my question, What is the real difference between the two?

Comment: You can see exactly what `Link` adds on top of the standard `a` tag if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087007/react-link-vs-a-tag-and-arrow-function and https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md these explains clearly

Comment: As far as I know, anchor tag will refresh the whole page on click but Link will not refresh the page.