# difference between html tag "/href" and navlink or Link

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-navigation, react-router-v4

what is the difference between html tag "/href" and navlink provided by react-router to navigate the page? I can use both in order to navigate page to the different URL, so why there was need of introducing Navlink or Link?

Comment: check this out:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087007/react-link-vs-a-tag-and-arrow-function

Comment: Navlink or Link both are parts of react Routing...whereas href is HTML <a> Attribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `href` attribute would trigger a page refresh which would reset the application states. However the link and navlink of react-router doesn't trigger a page refresh. Since React is used to create single page applications most of the time make sure you choose Link or Navlink when working with routing

Comment: but both navlink and link render a regular a tag in the end?

Comment: Yes, when you use inspect the rendered page using `inspect element` in the browser, you will find an `a` tag.

Comment: so why doesn't the (a)nchor tag causes browser to navigate when you click it?

Comment: Its because there is an event attached to the `a` tag which overrides the default behavior. It happens behind the scenes. Some browsers show tags which have events associated with them when you check on inspect element.

Comment: i checked a tag for onclick events there was one, but it was oop, and had no effect if i removed it, maybe events are attached up higher in dom hierarchy

Comment: ok there is a click handler event on document, `dispatchInteractiveEvent`, which is responsible for this. "event delegation"

Answer (score 2):

If we were to create links using anchor elements such as `href`, clicking on them would cause the whole page to reload. React Router provides a `<Link>` component to prevent that from happening. When clicking a `<Link>`, the URL will be updated and the rendered content will change without reloading the page. So basically to sum up this
navlink/ link provided by react doesnt refresh the page while href refreshes the page

Answer (score 1):

When you need to use style or class attributes on active , then you can use **navlink**

Let see the example:

**Link**

a primary way to allow users to navigate around your application.  will render a fully accessible anchor tag with the proper **href**.

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
```

**NavLink**

A special version of the  that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL.

```
<NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
```