# React-router or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-v4

I'm currently making a react application with create-react-app
It's a single page with several sections (Home / About / Contact ...)
Each section is a component that I export, of course.
Currently my App.js is like this :

**App.jsx**

```
import Menu from './components/menu/Menu';
import Header from './components/header/Header';
import Home from './components/sections/00_home/Home';
import About from './components/sections/01_about/About';
import Works from './components/sections/02_works/Works';
import Contact from './components/sections/03_contact/Contact';

const App = () => {
   return (
      <div className={styles.Container}>
         <Menu />
         <Header />
         <Home />
         <About />
         <Works />
         <Contact />
      </div>
   );
};

export default App;
```

***index.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

/* CSS */
import './index.css';

/* JSX */
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

To go from one section to another I use the anchor tag href's
For example in the home section, I have links to the other sections, same for the menu.

---

So far so good for me, but I'm wondering a question. 
Should I use ***react-router***? If so, why? 
In which situation should I use it ?
If someone could enlighten me on that, that'd be great.

Is the way I currently code unconventional?

Ced.

Comment: have you referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53862705/difference-between-html-tag-href-and-navlink-or-link) ?

Comment: Sounds like you don't need `react-router`. `react-router` is needed if you actually need to change your URL to a different path excluding the anchor tag.

Comment: I'm think things are me clear for me, I saw that https://markadamfoster.com/react-anchor-tags-vs-link-components/

Comment: And react router is essential for SEO !! damn it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, perhaps you misunderstood the single-page application (SPA) theory which is the main reason for why we have to adopt React Router instead of html hrefs. A brief clear overview from quick gg is that **"React Router, a dynamic, client-side routing, allows us to build a single-page web application with navigation without the page refreshing as the user navigates. React Router uses component structure to call components, which display the appropriate information."**

So when you are having some shared components and you want to write less code and avoid reloads whenever user navigate around which is quite annoying then React router is a solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are few differences in both which are quite important:

1. React-router: You can define the links you wanna go to and with the help of Link tag you define the URL in other components. In this situation, the `Link` tag will not refresh the page but instead would go onto the corresponding page but `a href` will refresh the page.
2. It might be difficult for you to pass information between components, as it is an important concept behind react.
3. Another would be an example, like if you are on `/classes` link and you go for `a href` tag, then it that case it will redirect you (i.e., you are using a relative path) to the `/classes/teachers` page, but you might want to go to `/teachers` URL. With the lp of Link and router, when you provide `/teachers`, it will redirect you to this URL

I have also started working on react and these are the points I came through.

Comment: Hey you answer help me  a lot but I can't accept two answers. Really apreciate it.