# hover underline - react router link vs styled-component link

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I am using two different links:

For this styled-component link, when I hover over it, it gets underlined. I don't want that to happen.

```
export const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  href: #;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
`;

<StyledLink href={'/login'}> SIGN</StyledLink>
```

Second link is like this:

```
<Link className="link-buttons" to={'/login'}>
        {' '}
        Contact
      </Link>

  .link-buttons{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

The css is same. Then why is the first one acting differently?

Comment: How are they different?

Comment: In my application, if I hover over the StyledLink, it gets underlined. I don't want that. However, in my second Contact link, it doesn't get underlined, even though the css looks same @O.o

Comment: Can you please check this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087007/react-link-vs-a-tag-and-arrow-function

Comment: Couldn't manage to reproduce it. Check the online demo https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hooks-npl8q

Comment: are you using react-router or react-router-dom?

Comment: @O.o reacher-router-dom but what difference would it make in this case?

Comment: @DanielLee I fixed the issue (see the ans). But just out of curiosity, what exactly are you pointing out? The href vs ```to```thing? ```to={}```didn't work inside the StyledLink but href works fine

Comment: @keikai it looks like I was doing the same thing as you. Anyhow, I fixed it (see and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this in the StyledLink worked:

```
 &:focus, &:hover, &:visited, &:link, &:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so suddenly it just worked by in _app.tsx using:

```
import "../styles/globals.scss";
```

**globals.scss:**

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

a:hover -webkit-any-link {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: "none";
}
```

**Links look like this:**

```
import NextLink from "next/link";
import Link from "@chakra-ui/react";

  <NextLink href="/" passHref>
    <Link>
       Link
    </Link>
  </NextLink>
```

Cheers