# Why use history.push or some other method from react-router-dom instead of just assigning the path to window.location.pathname?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

It seems easier to me when I need to navigate somewhere in my code to just assign the path where I want to go to window.location.pathname.  Is there any disadvantage to doing this?

Comment: Because `window.location.pathname` triggers a reload, defeating the entire purpose of react-router, while `history.push()` just changes the url and doesn't reload. Not reloading the entire page is one of the fundamentals of a single-page-application, SPA. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history

Comment: Thanks - I thought I had an issue in my authentication code that was causing those reloads. Just marked two issues off my list. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `window.location.pathname` triggers a reload, defeating the entire purpose of react-router, while `history.push()` just changes the url and doesn't reload. Not reloading the entire page is one of the fundamentals of a single-page-application, SPA. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history

Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43986829/12101554

Answer (score 3):

`history.push` doesn't cause your page to reload, `window.location` causes a page reload.
The exact thing for `<Link>` and `<a>`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `history.push` it redirects to the next page without reloading the entire page after adding it to the stack `[array]` of history and this feature is the main concept of the single-page applications

but `window.location` reload all of the page